# Can I use Siri to remember a parking spot?

Tags: ios, siri, geolocation, navigation

Can I use Siri to remember a particular GPS location, then later navigate back to it? It seems like it should be possible but I don't know what the voice directive would be.

I occasionally use a car-share program that only offers two-way rentals. In other words, I have to return the car to the exact spot I picked it up at. It would be helpful if I could use Siri to mark the location where I picked up the car, so that later I could get turn-by-turn navigation directions back to that parking spot.

Comment: If this is a specific space in an off-road location [car park etc] then Apple Maps cannot route to it, even if you can pin it it will fail to route there properly. This has been the case for years. Pin saves correctly, navigation goes to postcode/zipcode… not the pin. When you get out of the car it will pin your location & can navigate back to it if you're walking, but it will forget if you drive anywhere else after.

Comment: Just a side note - Apple does this automagically when you pair your iPhone to bluetooth in a car or use CarPlay. There might be a second question needed for the general case when iOS doesn’t already drop a pin when bluetooth or a beacon falls out of range for the maps app.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Source](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/11/30/how-to-use-siri-to-remember-where-you-parked-your-car/):

Yes, you can use Siri for this.

Simply say "Siri, remember where I parked my car."

Siri will drop a pin at the GPS location you're at.  You can use Maps to go back to this location.

[image]

As long as the parking location is marked, you can launch the stock Maps app on your iPhone and easily get walking directions to your parked car. This way, you’ll never have that lost look on your face ever again.

[image]

When you want to delete this parking spot, say "Siri, forget where I parked my car."  This will make Siri delete the pin.

Comment: Does that retain the data if you subsequently get in another car? ie, does SIri have more than one 'parked location'?

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't know, I've never had to try that.

Comment: When you want to make enemies, shout "Siri, forget where I parked my car" loudly in a crowded room.

Comment: @user253751 Note that Siri by default doesn't listen if your phone is locked AFAIK. so if you do this, not everyone will be bothered by it that much.

Comment: "Hey Siri" or even "Hey Sis" or anything close to that will wake random phones in the area, locked or not. The TV sets ours off at random times, as do non-siri-related phrases… ymmv ;)

Comment: That's not correct.  I have multiple Apple devices from 5 different people in my house.  When I say 'Hey Siri' only my devices wake-up.  I'm not sure what's happening at your house but the TV statements don't wake up any of our devices.  @Nzall Siri will listen if your device is locked.  I use it that way all the time.

Comment: If your iPhone connects to your car via Bluetooth, Siri will automatically remember the position where it was disconnected as the parking location. Doesn’t work in a garage though (obviously a GPS signal is needed in that moment).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to save a location with Siri, but you could take a photo of the car when you park, as long as the Camera app has location permission.

Then use an app like [Photo Find](https://apps.apple.com/app/id939480376) to make use of that location to do whatever is convenient for you:

- navigate back to it later on foot
- open the location from that app in your favorite navigation app to get turn-by-turn directions
- copy the coordinates from the photo to give to someone else

Comment: Looks like this is possible in iOS 13 without using a third party app. Go into Photos, open the photo, swipe up, and tap the line of text with the address. Cool tip!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't help your car share situation, but is useful for an owned car: If you link your phone using Bluetooth to your car, whenever you park and it disconnects, the iPhone remembers that location and you can see it on Maps as "parked car".

Comment: Why do you think it won't help the car-share situation?  Siri will mark your location whether you're using your own vehicle or not.  It's just using a GPS location.

Comment: @fsb It wouldn't help my car-share situation because I'm not interested in where I parked the car; I specifically want to know where it originated from. Allowing my phone to pair with the car could potentially overwrite the location info I might try to save with the "remember where I parked" trick, which is quite unhelpful in my case.

Comment: I'm not understanding. When you pickup the car you ask siri to mark your parking spot. If you're worried about it being overwritten, you have the pin in Maps now so you save it and/or rename it. It seems like it will work for this situation.

Comment: Indeed, my note was only automatically remember where you parked, not where to return the car to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Siri can do that, but Maps (and several third-party apps) will let you mark a location and later plot a route to or from that spot.

Or if you note the **address** of the spot, you can ask Siri to show directions to the **address**.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with iOS 12, you can use [Siri Shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209055) to define custom voice cues that will capture the current location into a Note, and navigate to the location stored in a Note. Examples:

---

Hey Siri, **save this parking spot**.

- Get Current Location
- Save into a Note

---

Hey Siri, **return to parking spot**.

- Get location from Note
- Get directions to location